# dropdown menu with images (no libs like jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

i am creating a dropdown menu with images in it. my goals are:

- it must not use any external libraries (so jquery is out)
- it should use css in preferance to javascript where possible
- it must be cross browser compatible
- the functionality must be the same as a regular html select-option dropdown menu
- it must fall back to a regular select-options html dropdown menu when javascript is not enabled

i have largely gotten there, here is the code i have which is roughly working:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"/>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
.select_outermost_unfocus
{
    background-color:red;
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;/*initial value - will be changed with js*/

    /*prevent highlighting*/
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.select_outermost_unfocus:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select_outermost_focus:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select_outermost_focus/*when the select area is clicked then cap its size*/
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
    height: 100px;
}
.select_outermost_focus:focus .unchosen_element/*when the select area is clicked then show all options*/
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.chosen_element
{
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
    white-space: nowrap;/*keep text on one line*/
    clear: both;
}
.unchosen_element
{
    background-color:grey;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;/*keep text on one line*/
    clear:both;
}
#invisible_screen
{
    background-color:green;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
//global vars
selected_element_id = 'option1';//initialise
showing_options = false;
window.onload = function() {
//  if(document.getElementById('no_tabindex').getAttribute('tabIndex') !== null) { //mimic safari
    if(document.getElementById('select_pretty').getAttribute('tabIndex') !== null) {
        document.getElementById('fallback_select').style.display = 'none';/*hide the html select element*/
        document.getElementById('select_pretty').style.display = 'inline-block';/*show the js pretty select element*/
        instate_select_box();
        hide_options();
    }
    else {
        alert('tabindex not supported - could be safari');
    };
};
function show_options(e) {
    showing_options = true;
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').onmouseup = null; //kill the event until unhover
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').className = 'select_outermost_focus';
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').focus();/*invoke class .select_outermost_focus .unchosen_element*/
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('option1').onmousedown = function() {option_clicked('option1');};
        document.getElementById('option2').onmousedown = function() {option_clicked('option2');};
        document.getElementById('option3').onmousedown = function() {option_clicked('option3');};
        document.getElementById('option4').onmousedown = function() {option_clicked('option4');};
        document.getElementById('option5').onmousedown = function() {option_clicked('option5');};
    }, 500);
};
function option_clicked(option_id) {
    document.getElementById(selected_element_id).className = 'unchosen_element';
    selected_element_id = option_id;//save globally
    document.getElementById(selected_element_id).className = 'chosen_element';
    hide_options();
//  document.getElementById('select_pretty').onmouseout = instate_select_box;
    instate_select_box();
};
function instate_select_box(e) {
//alert('mouseout');
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').onmouseup = show_options;//ready for next time the box is neded
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').onmouseout = null;
};
function hide_options() {
    if(!showing_options) {return;};
    document.getElementById('option1').onclick = null;
    document.getElementById('option2').onclick = null;
    document.getElementById('option3').onclick = null;
    document.getElementById('option4').onclick = null;
    document.getElementById('option5').onclick = null;
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').className = 'select_outermost_unfocus';
    showing_options = false;
};
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='no_tabindex'></div>
        <div id='fallback_select'>
            <select>
                <option>andora</option>
                <option>uae</option>
                <option>afghanistan</option>
                <option>cook islands</option>
                <option>germany</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <a class='select_outermost_unfocus' id='select_pretty' tabindex=0>
            <div class='chosen_element' id='option1'><img src='http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/misc/wad.gif'>andora</div>
            <div class='unchosen_element' id='option2'><img src='http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/misc/wae.gif'>uae</div>
            <div class='unchosen_element' id='option3'><img src='http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/misc/waf.gif'>afghanistan</div>
            <div class='unchosen_element' id='option4'><img src='http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/misc/wck.gif'>cook islands</div>
            <div class='unchosen_element' id='option5'><img src='http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/misc/wde.gif'>germany</div>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

its not currently very pretty, but that will be easy to fix up once i get the functionality working.

the problem i am having is that when i click on the very first option to select it, it gets selected but then fires the event to display all of the options again. this is obviously not how regular html select-option dropdown menus work.

i have tried implement a latch and also a timeout, but so far i have not had success with either of these. i am currently testing on chrome. can anyone get it to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out how to solve your problem, but eventually I found a solution.

The solution I'm talking about requires a variable `mousedown`, which tells us whether `select_pretty` is being clicked. If it is, `option_clicked` should not proceed, unless `mousedown` is `false`.

There are also a few changes to when some of the event handlers take action. Look at the code below and compare with the original version.

Here's your working dropdown menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"/>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
.select_outermost_unfocus
{
    background-color:red;
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;/*initial value - will be changed with js*/

    /*prevent highlighting*/
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.select_outermost_unfocus:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select_outermost_focus:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select_outermost_focus/*when the select area is clicked then cap its size*/
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
    height: 100px;
}
.select_outermost_focus:focus .unchosen_element/*when the select area is clicked then show all options*/
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.chosen_element
{
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
    white-space: nowrap;/*keep text on one line*/
    clear: both;
}
.unchosen_element
{
    background-color:grey;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;/*keep text on one line*/
    clear:both;
}
#invisible_screen
{
    background-color:green;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
//global vars
selected_element_id = 'option1';//initialise
showing_options = false;
mousedown = false;
window.onload = function() {
//  if(document.getElementById('no_tabindex').getAttribute('tabIndex') !== null) { //mimic safari
    if(document.getElementById('select_pretty').getAttribute('tabIndex') !== null) {
        document.getElementById('fallback_select').style.display = 'none';/*hide the html select element*/
        document.getElementById('select_pretty').style.display = 'inline-block';/*show the js pretty select element*/
        instate_select_box();
        hide_options();
    }
    else {
        alert('tabindex not supported - could be safari');
    };
};
function show_options(e) {
    showing_options = true;
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').onmousedown = null; //kill the event until unhover
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').className = 'select_outermost_focus';
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').focus();/*invoke class .select_outermost_focus .unchosen_element*/
    document.getElementById('option1').onmouseup = function() {option_clicked('option1');};
    document.getElementById('option2').onmouseup = function() {option_clicked('option2');};
    document.getElementById('option3').onmouseup = function() {option_clicked('option3');};
    document.getElementById('option4').onmouseup = function() {option_clicked('option4');};
    document.getElementById('option5').onmouseup = function() {option_clicked('option5');};
};
function option_clicked(option_id) {
    if (mousedown)
        return;

    document.getElementById(selected_element_id).className = 'unchosen_element';
    selected_element_id = option_id;//save globally
    document.getElementById(selected_element_id).className = 'chosen_element';
    hide_options();
//  document.getElementById('select_pretty').onmouseout = instate_select_box;
    instate_select_box();
};
function select_pretty_mousedown(e)
{
    mousedown = true;
    show_options();
};
function select_pretty_mouseup(e)
{
    mousedown = false;
};
function instate_select_box(e) {
//alert('mouseout');
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').onmousedown = select_pretty_mousedown;
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').onmouseup = select_pretty_mouseup;
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').onmouseout = null;
};
function hide_options() {
    if(!showing_options) {return;};
    document.getElementById('option1').onmouseup = null;
    document.getElementById('option2').onmouseup = null;
    document.getElementById('option3').onmouseup = null;
    document.getElementById('option4').onmouseup = null;
    document.getElementById('option5').onmouseup = null;
    document.getElementById('select_pretty').className = 'select_outermost_unfocus';
    showing_options = false;
};
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='no_tabindex'></div>
        <div id='fallback_select'>
            <select>
                <option>andora</option>
                <option>uae</option>
                <option>afghanistan</option>
                <option>cook islands</option>
                <option>germany</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <a class='select_outermost_unfocus' id='select_pretty' tabindex=0>
            <div class='chosen_element' id='option1'><img src='http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/misc/wad.gif'>andora</div>
            <div class='unchosen_element' id='option2'><img src='http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/misc/wae.gif'>uae</div>
            <div class='unchosen_element' id='option3'><img src='http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/misc/waf.gif'>afghanistan</div>
            <div class='unchosen_element' id='option4'><img src='http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/misc/wck.gif'>cook islands</div>
            <div class='unchosen_element' id='option5'><img src='http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/misc/wde.gif'>germany</div>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: most excellent! if you like i shall wait until i can make this a bounty then award you the points? i've been tearing my hair out on this one for at least 2 days so you can imagine i'm pretty grateful :)

Comment: @mulllhausen I'm glad I've helped you. :) If you think my answer deserves extra points, then – yes, make a bounty. But I won't be angry at you if you don't.

Comment: absolutely. also, i have managed to simplify some javascript into css by changing `.select_outermost_focus` into `.select_outermost:focus`